# In a linked list is it necessary to name all the individual nodes?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a hashtable to store words from a txt file. Is it necessary to create a new name for every node I wish to add?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. But what sort of names were you thinking of? Variable names? A string added to each node?

Comment: Thanks, I'm just trying to figure out how to create a new node for each word. So I guess the because they are linked the variable name is unnecessary?

Comment: In the question title you ask about a linked list, then in the question body you are creating a hash table. Which is it?

Comment: A variable name is not needed because memory for each node is allocated with `malloc` or a related routine, and that memory is managed using pointers, not named variables.

Comment: Many thanks, yes this makes it clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes themselves don't need a name, however they do need to be hashed someway through a key. That could be the word itself, a name, or a randomly generated UID.